# DISCORD // 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Tags: python

I'm trying to open discord with this script

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['C:\Users\xerxe\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Discord Inc\\Discord.exe'])
```

but only get this this error

```
'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\` character is an escape character - `\n` means a newline character, `\t` is a tab character, etc. `\U` is used to denote the beginning of a Unicode escape sequence, like `\U000145d3`, where the 8 chars following `\U` are hex digits (`0-9a-f`). Since `\Users\xer` is not a valid Unicode escape sequence, you got an error. For Windows paths, you either need to escape the escape character:

```
subprocess.call(['C:\\Users\\xerxe\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Discord Inc\\Discord.exe'])
```

use a raw string literal (note the `r` just before the opening `'`):

```
subprocess.call([r'C:\Users\xerxe\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Discord Inc\Discord.exe'])
```

or use `/` characters as path delimiters:

```
subprocess.call(['C:/Users/xerxe/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Discord Inc/Discord.exe'])
```